# Sum of 1st N natural numbers in O(no. of digits in N)

Tags: python, algorithm, sum, biginteger

I'm trying to write a program to find sum of first N natural numbers i.e. `1 + 2 + 3 + .. + N` modulo 1000000009

I know this can be done by using the formula `N * (N+1) / 2` but I'm trying to find a sort of recursive function to calculate the sum.

I tried searching the web, but I didn't get any solution to this.

Actually, the problem here is that the number `N` can have upto 100000 digits.

So, here is what I've tried until now.

First I tried splitting the number into parts each of length 9, then convert them into integers so that I can perform arithmetic operations using the operators for integers.

For example, the number `52562372318723712` will be split into `52562372` & `318723712`.
But I didn't find a way to manipulate these numbers.

Then again I tried to write a function as follows:

```
def find_sum(n):
    # n is a string
    if len(n) == 1:
        # use the formula if single digit
        return int(int(n[0]) * (int(n[0]) + 1) / 2)

    # I'm not sure what to return here
    # I'm expecting some manipulation with n[0] 
    # and a recursive call to the function itself

    # I've also not used modulo here just for testing with smaller numbers
    # I'll add it once I find a solution to this
    return int(n[0]) * something + find_sum(n[1:])
```

I'm not able to find the `something` here. 
Can this be solved like this?
or is there any other method to do so?

NOTE: I prefer a solution similar to the above function because I want to modify this function to meet my other requirements which I want to try myself before asking here. But if it is not possible, any other solution will also be helpful.

Please give me any hint to solve it.

Comment: Are you aware of [the properties of modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties), especially that (a*b)(mod n) = a (mod n) * b (mod n)?

Comment: Yes I do. I've just not used it here until now because I was trying with smaller numbers.

Comment: My plan was to find a solution first and then use the properties

Comment: It might be better to work with smaller numbers *using* the properties (for example, compute the sum modulo 109).

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or the old Python 2?

Comment: After one valid answer and reading your question and comments, I still have no idea what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to just use the `N*(N+1)/2` formula -- but using it mod `p`. The only tricky part is to interpret division by 2 -- this had to be the inverse of 2 mod `p`. For `p` prime (or simply for `p` odd) this is very easy to compute: it is just `(p+1)//2`.

Thus:

```
def find_sum(n,p):
    two_inv = (p+1)//2 #inverse of 2, mod p
    return ((n%p)*((n+1)%p)*two_inv)%p
```

For example:

```
>>> find_sum(10000000,1000000009)
4550000
>>> sum(range(1,10000001))%1000000009
4550000
```

Note that the above function will fail if you pass an even number for `p`.

**On Edit** as @user11908059 observed, it is possible to dispense with multiplication by the modular inverse of 2. As an added benefit, this approach no longer depends on the modulus being odd:

```
def find_sum2(n,k):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        a,b = (n//2) % k, (n+1) % k
    else:
        a,b = n % k, ((n+1)//2) % k
    return (a*b) % k
```

Comment: I already tried this one. The problem here is the number can contain 10^5 digits! Your solution won't work with such large numbers.

Comment: @sanketd617 Give an example for which the function does not work. `find_sum(10**(10**5),1000000009)` is no problem. Python ints can handle very large numbers.

Comment: Python 3 handles big integers internally so it allows performing arithmetics on arbitrarily long numbers. Even just doing `(N * (N + 1) / 2) % p` would still be fine.

Comment: Actually your answer works for what I asked. But as I mentioned in the question that I want to modify it for some other requirement. Still for this question, I'm marking it as solved as you answered what I asked for. Thank you for your precious time :)

Comment: @saketd617 You might want to have a look at https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/ to understand how Python handles big integer arithmetics internally for your purpose, in case you need to implement something similar yourself based on that.

Comment: @GZ0 Thanks a lot.